# Handles and pointer to object

Tags: c++, object, pointers, handles

I have a python Interpreter written in C++, the PyRun_String function from the Python API is said to return a handle, however in my code I have it assigned to pointer to a `PyObject`?

```
PyObject* presult = PyRun_String(code, parse_mode, dict, dict);
```

Is this actually correct?  Can you implicitly cast this handle to this object pointer?

Should it not be a HANDLE instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "handle" in API documentation usually does not refer specifically to the `HANDLE` type, but rather to any type intended to be opaque to the user.

`PyRun_String` in particular returns a `PyObject*`, there is no cast going on.